# Validate active accordion panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, panel

I have a bootstrap accordion:

[image: Accordion]

And I want to disable all input controls in inactive panels. To validate just active panel.

I have a function to detect active tab:

```
$(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    if (e.type=='show'){
        console.log($(this));

    } else {

    }
});
```

But how to disable inputs in inactive tabs (PayPal in the case above)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$('.accordion-body:not(.in) > .input-for-paypal').prop('disabled', true)
```

the content that is shown has the class .in, so negate it and you get the hidden accordion-body

Comment: Disabled panel may contain other type of inputs. E.g: select, input, radio, checkbox, textarea and other. And I don't know input classes.

Comment: "And I want to disable all input controls in inactive panels. To validate just active panel." You can specify which element you want to disable. The selector ":not(.in)" should be the interesting part.